# Is this expectation $\mathbb E\big[{\bf 1}_{\{x+\inf_{0\le t\le 2}W_t>0\}}(W_{\tau}-y)^+\big]$ strictly positive?

Tags: brownian-motion, expectation

Let $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and $\tau$ be a stopping time lying in $[1,2]$. For $x, y>0$, can we show

$$\mathbb E\big[{\bf 1}_{\{x+\inf_{0\le t\le 2}W_t>0\}}(W_{\tau}-y)^+\big]>0?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A= \{W_1>y+2, \, \inf_{0 \le t \le 1} W_t >-x\}.$
By the reflection principle,
$$P(A)=P(W_1>y+2)-P(W_1<-2x-y-2)$$ $$=P(W_1>y+2)-P(W_1>2x+y+2)>0\,.$$
Let $D= \{ \inf_{1 \le t \le 2} W_t >y\}.$ Then by the Markov property and the reflection principle,
$$P(D|A) \ge P(\inf_{0 \le t \le 1} W_t >-1)=P(W_1>-1)-P(W_1<-1)=P(W_1 \in (-1,1]\:)>0\,.$$
Thus $P(D)>0$. We deduce that
$$\mathbb E\big[{\bf 1}_{\{x+\inf_{0\le t\le 2}W_t>0\}}(W_{\tau}-y)^+\big]>0$$
Since the integrand is strictly positive on the event $D$.

Comment: Thank you very kindly for the answer